# Selenium Webdriver: Writing file to excel fails even though value is fetched properly from other excel

Tags: java

Please find the attached code snippet and please help me to proceed with this. I am trying to read data from one excel and then write the same to another excel , while trying to write the file it's stopping the code. When I tried debugging I could see that value is properly fetched but write is not working.

```
package Export;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class TestExport
{
    XSSFWorkbook xlsxworkbook;
    HSSFWorkbook xlsworkbook;
    XSSFWorkbook xlsxworkbook1;
    HSSFWorkbook xlsworkbook1;
    Sheet sheet; 
    Sheet sheet1; 
    TestExport(){
        xlsxworkbook=null;
        xlsworkbook=null;
        sheet=null;
        xlsxworkbook1=null;
        xlsworkbook1=null;
        sheet1=null;
    }

    public void readExcel(String filePath,String fileName,String sheetName,String filePath1,String fileName1,String sheetName1) 
    {
        try{
        FileInputStream fs=new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\Susmitha-Phases\\Desktop\\TestWorkbook.xlsx"));
        FileOutputStream fi=new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\Susmitha-Phases\\Desktop\\TestWorkbook1.xlsx"));
        fs.toString();
        if(fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith("xlsx")){
            xlsxworkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
            sheet=xlsxworkbook.getSheet(sheetName);
           xlsxworkbook1 = new XSSFWorkbook();
           sheet1=xlsxworkbook.getSheet(sheetName1);
        }
        else{
            xlsworkbook=new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
            sheet=xlsworkbook.getSheet(sheetName);
          xlsworkbook1=new HSSFWorkbook();
           sheet1=xlsworkbook.getSheet(sheetName1);
        }
        int rowCount = sheet.getLastRowNum()-sheet.getFirstRowNum();

        //Create a loop over all the rows of excel file to read it
        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount+1; i++) 
        {
            Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
           Row row1=sheet1.getRow(i);
            //Create a loop to print cell values in a row
            for (int j = 0; j < row.getLastCellNum(); j++) 
            {
                String temp= row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
                row1.createCell(i).setCellValue(temp);

                //Print Excel data in console
                System.out.print(row1.getCell(j).getStringCellValue()+"|| ");
                 xlsworkbook.write(fi);
                //System.out.print(row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue()+"|| ");
            }

        }

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        //Create an object of ReadGuru99ExcelFile class

        TestExport objExcelFile = new TestExport();

        //Prepare the path of excel file

        String filePath = System.getProperty("C:\\Users\\Susmitha-Phases\\Desktop\\TestWorkbook.xlsx");
        String filePath1 = System.getProperty("C:\\Users\\Susmitha-Phases\\Desktop\\TestWorkbook1.xlsx");

        //Call read file method of the class to read data

        objExcelFile.readExcel(filePath,"TestWorkbook.xlsx","Sheet1",filePath1,"TestWorkbook1.xlsx","Sheet1");

        }
}
```

Comment: Did you get any error?

Comment: No, there was no error.

Comment: @sumitha narayanan You must change your logic .

Answer (score 0):

There are some problem with your code it possible throw null pointer exception

You never created the instance for `xlsworkbook` in your class when the file type `xlsx` and trying to write the file . which is wrong will throw definitely null pointer exception. so You must change the logic while writing which file type should be write . Probably you can check file type and write the file.